# Gluster snapshot directory error: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: glusterfs, glusterfs-3.5

When I try to access the snapshot directory for a volume, I keep getting `.snaps: Transport endpoint is not connected` I killed and started the glusterd service but still keep getting that error message. Does anyone has an idea how I can resolve this? I am at a loss as to what else to do to fix this issue. I am able to access the volume fine and all bricks in the cluster are online.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the nodes seemed to have fixed the issue.